# Grouping posts by user in has_many through relation collection with Rails 5

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, group-by, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many

I'm trying to display Users (devise) in a collection (has_many through).

```
    <%= @collection.posts.count %> designs by
    <% @collection.posts.each do |post| %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(post.designer.avatar.url.to_s, class: "avatar-small"), post.designer %>
    <% end %>
```

but it displaying duplicates as in

[image]

I need to group by designer.id. So I added @collection_designers line but I could not manage to group by designer id.‍♂️

```
class CollectionsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @collection = Collection.find(params[:id])

    #I need to group for designer.id I guess but I could not manage it
    @collection_designers = Collection.find(params[:id]).groups(designers.id) 
  end

  ...
```

---

**Relations:**

models/collection.rb

```
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :designer
  has_many :collectivizations
  has_many :posts, through: :collectivizations
end
```

models/collectivization.rb

```
class Collectivization < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :collection
end
```

models/post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :designer
  has_many :collectivizations
  has_many :collections, through: :collectivizations
```

Comment: Collection will have many designers through posts, right ? Why did you add `belongs_to : designer ` again in collection ? Is that different one ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to find uniq designers ids at first

```
designer_ids = @collection.posts.distinct.pluck(:designer_id)
```

And after it find designers by these ids

```
@designers = Designer.where(id: designer_ids)
```

Comment: ah I didnt know about that **map** and **.uniq** feature. Awesome. It works great. thank you!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Why do you use uniq and map, having pluck and distinct for that purposes?

Comment: Thank you, @SebastianPalma, very important notes! I didn't think enough about my answer

Comment: @Designer, I've updated the answer according to the last comment. `pluck` selects only one field from db, so it works much faster. `distinct` works on the db level, so it is faster too